How to Log Custom Metrics with Metadata in Hugging Face Trainer during Evaluation?
I'm working on a sentence regression task using Hugging Face’s Trainer. Each sample consists of:
input_ids: The tokenized sentence.
labels: A numerical scalar target (for regression).
metadata: A categorical string field (e.g., project_name or task_type).
My Goal:
I want to log custom metrics with respect to the metadata during evaluation. Specifically, I need to calculate the loss grouped by each metadata category (e.g., loss per project or task). the main loss for gradient computation is still the global loss but i want to pass the metadata to the compute_metrics function
What I’ve Tried:
Modified the Dataset:
My dataset returns a dictionary containing:
{
    "input_ids": input_ids,
    "labels": torch.tensor([numerical_score]),  # Scalar target
    "metadata": project_name  # Metadata field
}

Updated the Collator:
I ensured that all elements (including metadata) are passed correctly to the model.
Trainer Setup:
I enabled include_inputs_for_metrics=True to access inputs in compute_metrics:
Trainer(..., compute_metrics=compute_metrics, args=TrainingArguments(include_inputs_for_metrics=True))

However, metadata still gets lost in the evaluation loop, and I can’t access it directly inside compute_metrics.
The Problem:
The compute_metrics function only receives predictions and labels, and not the additional metadata. I need a way to log metrics with respect to metadata without completely overriding the Trainer class or the entire evaluation loop, as this would be cumbersome to maintain, especially in parallel runs.
What I Want to Achieve:
Log metrics grouped by metadata categories.
For example, calculate the loss per project or task.
Minimize complex modifications to the Hugging Face Trainer class.
Ensure the solution works with the default Trainer evaluation loop to maintain scalability and parallelism.
Potential Solutions Explored:
i tried to make a metadata string, encode it using the tokenizer and pass it along as metadata or as labels, but it causes an infinite hang which i suspect is related to the gather function not expecting something about the shape.
Is there a clean and efficient way to pass metadata through the evaluation loop and use it in compute_metrics? How can I log metrics grouped by metadata without having to rewrite the Trainer class or evaluation loop entirely?
Any suggestions or best practices would be greatly appreciated!
